# does glassfish SSO implement any standards?

Tags: glassfish

Does the glassfish [SSO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacq.html) implementation implement any standards?  If so, which ones?

If I have a dependency on Glassfish SSO for my applications, will my applications be portable - will the SSO work if I deploy my applications to another web container such as tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the GlassFish implementation is based on the Tomcat valve [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On) and not on a Java/Java EE standard.

It should be possible to port applications to other app servers that are based on Tomcat, though I would recommend doing some tests first.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish, like many (all?) containers, uses the concept of a Realm when working with container-based security. I don't know if there's a standard to define a Realm, but certainly code that we've written that delegates to the Realm runs in Tomcat, Glassfish and Jetty, and OSGi containers like Apache Karaf also have Realms that seem to be the same (but I haven't actually tried that one yet).

The SSO implementation is entirely on the container side - if several applications use the same realm, then you can configure the container to enable SSO across those applications. The fact that the Glassfish implementation of SSO is a tomcat valve is entirely hidden to the application - so long as the container supports realms, and can be configured to enable sso across applications using those realms, then the application is portable across any such container.

Caveat - this is all based on my (limited) real-world experience. I don't know how common Realms are, nor if there's any standards compliance between them. But for our use, they seem (so far) to be a reasonable, portable abstraction.